# Append field without data by ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, append

Is that possible to append data in view without sending any data to back-end?

I have static select-box with static values (nothing from database), i want when i selected specific option show some more fields and for other options hide those fields. **Is that possible**?

## Code

```
<select name="style" id="style" class="chosen-select">
    <option value="">-- Select --</option>
    <option value="default">Default</option>
    <option value="about-one">About Style 1</option>
    <option value="about-two">About Style 2</option>
    <option value="contact-one">Contact page without form</option>
    <option value="contact-two">Contact page with form</option>
    <option value="faq">Faq</option>
    <option value="services">Services</option>
</select>

//new fields here
<div class="col-md-12 mt-10" id="details"></div>
```

`JavaScript`

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('select[name="style"]').on('change', function() {
            $('div#details').empty();
            var Style = 'contact-two' //when this value is selected return below
            if(Style) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success:function() {
                        $('div#details').empty();
                        $('div#details').append('<p>Here will be appended inputs</p>');
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $('div#details').empty();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

> PS: Not sure I need Ajax at all?! Please share your ideas with me.

Comment: What is `field-1: field-2`? Please provide some example output.

Comment: @jom those will be the items that later i want to append i will replace them with inputs (you think of it as static text)

Comment: Its unclear what you are attempting. Do you just want to alter #details on the change of the select list, why are you using ajax at all? Also var Style = 'contact-two' does nothing useful for your if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant see the use in Ajax, perhaps you have a reason, but unless you need data from the server try this.

var Style = 'contact-two' does nothing in the if statement, the if is just checking that it is not null. Compare the string to the value of the select with this.value

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select[name="style"]').on('change', function(f) {
    $('#details').empty();
    if (this.style == 'contact-two'){
      $('#details').empty();
      $('#details').append('<p>Here will be appended inputs</p>');
    } else {
      $('div#details').empty();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: i'm getting `ReferenceError: Style is not define` perhaps we need to check `selected:option == 'contact-two'` instead of `Style == 'contact-two'`. what do you think?

Comment: @mafortis Wait, are you simply trying to check which `option` is selected and append these dynamic contents on the `#details`?

Comment: yes, i try to check if the option is selected value is equal to `contact-two` show details if any other option is selected dont show

Comment: @mafortis Well, then just do `if (this.value === 'contact-two') { // append stuff here } else { }`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Ajax. Just manipulate the innerHTML of the element you wish to change.

```js
var dropdown = document.getElementById('style')
var details = document.getElementById('details')
dropdown.onchange = (event) => {
  var selected = event.target.value

  if (selected == 'contact-two') {
    details.classList.remove('hidden')
    details.innerHTML = "<div>whatever html you want</div>"

  } else {
    details.innerHtml = "hi"
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="style" id="style" class="chosen-select">
  <option value="">-- Select --</option>
  <option value="default">Default</option>
  <option value="about-one">About Style 1</option>
  <option value="about-two">About Style 2</option>
  <option value="contact-one">Contact page without form</option>
  <option value="contact-two">Contact page with form</option>
  <option value="faq">Faq</option>
  <option value="services">Services</option>
</select>

<div class="col-md-12 mt-10" id="details">Hi</div>
```